# Can DNS be tracked in tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, vpn, dns

can DNS be tracked if I am using TOR without using more protection like VPN? For example, If someone tries to target me and have a DNS lookup, it will show my original DNS or I need to change it?
Thank You

Comment: VPNs actually decrease your privacy and anonymity. Don't use a VPN with Tor.

Answer (score 0):

no, exit nodes caches dns record and your dns lookup will be performed on exit relays. (i mean your tor browser not your system dns lookup ofcourse) also

tor+vpn is 99% a bad idea since you should trust the provider not to 'man in the middle' you

Comment: So my original DNS will not be spoofed. but instead, DNS which is recorded at the exit relay can be spoofed? Idk why I am really confused about this.

Comment: Tor browser will use exit relay's dns system. sorry for confusion

Comment: Okay got It , Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS queries will be routed through Tor. Websites you access, specifically host names when your browser sends a query (DMS), will not be visible to your ISP.
It should be noted however that your ISP will be able to see that you are using Tor. To obfuscate this you need to use a bridge.

Answer (score 0):

It can be tracked if it leaks, so - it's totally depends on a setup. But - to be 101% ensured that you're safe - use a local ISC BIND setup and route it properly to handle dot-onion domains